# C++ program dies when making a library call

Tags: c++, unix, solaris, coredump

Im a novice in C++. I added a new method in a library(its a simple method which prints a log and returns), and compiled it successfully.
Then I try to call that method from my program. The program dies without any warning when trying to call that function. There is no core dump to debug.

(The program runs fine when not calling this function and I tried, kill -s SIGSEGV $pid. At this instance the core dump is generated. So there is no problem in generating the core dump)

Since the program dies I cannot use pstack also. My debug logs indicate that call to the library never returns. My debug logs at the library also doesnt get printed.

There is no NULl pointer problems also, as I'm checking for NULL pointers before calling the library function

```
/* My Library function */

void EasyTaskScheduler::test1() {

 tauloginfo << "inside test1" << endlog;

 }


/* library call */

 if (mapper == NULL) {

  loggeneric << __FILE__ << "," << __LINE__ << "Is null:" << endlog;
  return -1;

}

 else {


  loggeneric << __FILE__ << "," << __LINE__ << "Im not NULL" << endlog;

  easyTaskScheduler->test1();

  loggeneric << __FILE__ << "," << __LINE__ << "Test function returns: " << endlog;

    return 0;

}
```

The last log I see is "Im not NULL"
and the program dies.
Can anyone give a hint what might be the problem.
Is there a place in solaris to check what happened to a program(why did it die, etc) without admin rights....

Comment: What is `endlog`, `tauloginfo` and `loggeneric`? Where is `tauloginfo` initialized/declared?

Comment: They have been defined in the header files. I guess no issue with them, as I'm using them to write to my log files

Comment: How do you compile and link the program and library? Ideally post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue. It was a silly mistake of mine.
Eventhough I compiled the library with the new function,  I didnt add it to the testing environment.
The testing environment had the older version of the library without the new function API

But quite surprised that the fucntion call didnt crash the program, or show any signs of problems